# How to go current viewController when Audio playing in swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

Currently, I build simple app music and I would like to do if I left my current viewcontroller(musicController) is playing to anotherController and I created one button "NowPlaying" put on anotherController to go my currently viewcontroller(musicController) without load any view. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any code? Perhaps the view controllers in question so we can see how they are connected in term of segues

Comment: I would like to to know the logic that I can do that. example viewController1 is my audio player and viewController2 is I stayed so I want to go back viewController1 without did load any view that still keep my audio playing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try my working code,**

```
var currentTopMostChildCont: UIViewController = self.getCurrentTopMostChildController()


func getCurrentTopMostChildController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController
    while topController.childViewControllers.count() > 0 {
        topController = topController.childViewControllers.last //You can track your viewController which you want & get it.
    }
    return topController
}
```

I hope this will surely help you.

Comment: I had looked your code. Could you explain me step by step ?

Comment: Bro, you adding each controller that mean in app delegate window rootVC has reference of each viewController, you need to just run loop & get viewcontroller you wants.